# Repeated code with different function name

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```cs
try
{
    if (_slideRange != null)
    {
        bool isSameTagValueBdd = true;
        QuizzDll.PowerPoints.PptTag_Slide_ByInterop firstTagSlide = new QuizzDll.PowerPoints.PptTag_Slide_ByInterop(_slideRange[1]);
        var result = firstTagSlide.GetValeur_CoefQuestion().ValueTagBdd;

        foreach (Slide slide in _slideRange)
        {
            QuizzDll.PowerPoints.PptTag_Slide_ByInterop objTagSlide = new QuizzDll.PowerPoints.PptTag_Slide_ByInterop(slide);
            if (objTagSlide.GetValeur_CoefQuestion().ValueTagBdd != result)
            {
                isSameTagValueBdd = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isSameTagValueBdd) { return result; }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.WriteLog(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - " + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace, 3);
}
```

I have to write it many many times, the only changing thing is the `GetValeur_XXX` function.
I don't know how to do to simplify this code to make it easier to use.

NOTE: the `GetValeur_XXX` functions return different structures as the result because `ValueTagBdd` can be of different type.

EDIT:

Here is the `GetValeur_CoefQuestion` code:

```vb
Public Function GetValeur_CoefQuestion() As TagQB.struct_VALUE_TAG_DOUBLE
    Dim sReturn As New TagQB.struct_VALUE_TAG_DOUBLE
    Dim strReturn As String = GetTagValue(TagNameSlideQuestion.PROP_SLIDE_QUESTION_COEF)
    If strReturn <> "" Then
        'sReturn.ValueTagBdd = CDbl(strReturn)
        sReturn.ValueTagBdd = Outil.Math.GetValeurDouble(strReturn) '#3493
    Else
        sReturn.ValueTagBdd = PARAM_SLIDE_QUESTION_DEFAULT_COEFFICIENT
    End If
    sReturn.ValueTag = sReturn.ValueTagBdd
    sReturn.ValueAffichProp = sReturn.ValueTagBdd
    sReturn.ValueAffichRapport = sReturn.ValueAffichProp
    sReturn.ValueCaption = TraductionHelper.GetDescriptionProp(PROPRIETE.PROP_SLIDE_QUESTION_COEF).Caption
    sReturn.ValueDesc = TraductionHelper.GetDescriptionProp(PROPRIETE.PROP_SLIDE_QUESTION_COEF).Description
    Return sReturn
End Function
```

And the structure used:

```vb
Public Structure struct_VALUE_TAG_DOUBLE
    Public ValueTag As String
    Public ValueTagBdd As Double
    Public ValueAffichProp As String
    Public ValueAffichRapport As String 
    Public ValueDesc As String
    Public ValueCaption As String
End Structure
```

Here is another `GetValeur_XXX` code used:

```vb
Public Function GetValeur_MalusTemps() As TagQB.struct_VALUE_TAG_STRING '#2142
    Dim sReturn As New TagQB.struct_VALUE_TAG_STRING
    Dim strReturn As String = GetTagValue(TagNameSlideQuestion.PROP_SLIDE_QUESTION_MALUS_TEMPS)
    If CalculPoint.cMalusTemps.IsDescriptionCorrect(strReturn) Then sReturn.ValueTag = strReturn Else sReturn.ValueTag = ""
    If sReturn.ValueTag.Length > 255 Then
        sReturn.ValueTagBdd = sReturn.ValueTag.Substring(0, 255)
    Else
        sReturn.ValueTagBdd = sReturn.ValueTag
    End If
    sReturn.ValueAffichProp = sReturn.ValueTag
    sReturn.ValueAffichRapport = sReturn.ValueAffichProp
    sReturn.ValueCaption = TraductionHelper.GetDescriptionProp(PROPRIETE.PROP_SLIDE_QUESTION_MALUS_TEMPS).Caption
    sReturn.ValueDesc = TraductionHelper.GetDescriptionProp(PROPRIETE.PROP_SLIDE_QUESTION_MALUS_TEMPS).Description
    Return sReturn
End Function
```

And the structure:

```vb
Public Structure struct_VALUE_TAG_STRING
    Public ValueTag As String
    Public ValueTagBdd As String
    Public ValueAffichProp As String
    Public ValueAffichRapport As String 
    Public ValueDesc As String
    Public ValueCaption As String
End Structure
```

And the code used to call this function is:

```cs
try
{
    if (_slideRange != null)
    {
        bool isSameTagValueBdd = true;
        QuizzDll.PowerPoints.PptTag_Slide_ByInterop firstTagSlide = new QuizzDll.PowerPoints.PptTag_Slide_ByInterop(_slideRange[1]);
        var result = firstTagSlide.GetValeur_CoefQuestion().ValueTagBdd;

        foreach (Slide slide in _slideRange)
        {
            QuizzDll.PowerPoints.PptTag_Slide_ByInterop objTagSlide = new QuizzDll.PowerPoints.PptTag_Slide_ByInterop(slide);
            if (objTagSlide.GetValeur_CoefQuestion().ValueTagBdd != result)
            {
                isSameTagValueBdd = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isSameTagValueBdd) { return result; }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.WriteLog(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - " + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace, 3);
}
```

As you can see I call the method in the same way, the only thing that changed is in bold in the following code:

```cs
try
{
    if (_slideRange != null)
    {
        bool isSameTagValueBdd = true;
        QuizzDll.PowerPoints.PptTag_Slide_ByInterop firstTagSlide = new QuizzDll.PowerPoints.PptTag_Slide_ByInterop(_slideRange[1]);
        var result = firstTagSlide.GetValeur_XXX().ValueTagBdd;

        foreach (Slide slide in _slideRange)
        {
            QuizzDll.PowerPoints.PptTag_Slide_ByInterop objTagSlide = new QuizzDll.PowerPoints.PptTag_Slide_ByInterop(slide);
            if (objTagSlide.GetValeur_XXX().ValueTagBdd != result)
            {
                isSameTagValueBdd = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isSameTagValueBdd) { return result; }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.WriteLog(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - " + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace, 3);
}
```

Comment: It's quite hard to suggest changes when we're missing *so* much context. I'd generally suggest a generic method accepting a delegate, but without having a complete example (e.g. with two similar methods) it's hard to be any more concrete than that.

Comment: It's not just the *name* that changes in these methods. They read from different fields with different types which have different comparison and conversion rules. It seems that the return fields are different too.

Comment: The code is very hard to read due to all those type prefix and suffixes. Using type may have been a good idea in C 30 years ago but it's not used in OOP languages. In this case it only adds noise and makes the code look similar when it isn't. For example, what's the difference between sReturn and strReturn? Why do I have to scroll to see what field is returned?. Why do all fields have a `Value` prefix, and structs `struct_`? We can see they're structs. If all prefixes are removed the two methods will look very different from each other

Comment: What you should be asking for is a _generic_ solution for the data model (the `struct`) and a generic method to resolve that data.

Comment: You should post some pseudo code, so we don't have to go through your specific details.